# Leer archivo de un Servidor FTP sin descargarlos a mi disco

Tags: c#, ftp, lista

Tengo una app que está leyendo archivos CSV de un Servidor FTP y lo descarga a una carpeta del disco

```
 private static void DownloadFtpDirectory(string url, NetworkCredential credentials, string localPath)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AcceptAllCertifications;
            FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            listRequest.EnableSsl = true;
            listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            listRequest.Credentials = credentials;

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            using (FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse())
            using (Stream listStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(listStream))
            {
                while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] tokens =
                    line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string name = tokens[8];
                string permissions = tokens[0];

                string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, name);
                string fileUrl = url + "/" + name;

                if (permissions[0] == 'd')
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(localFilePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(localFilePath);
                    }

                    DownloadFtpDirectory(fileUrl + "/", credentials, localFilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    FtpWebRequest downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
                    downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    downloadRequest.Credentials = credentials;

                    using (FtpWebResponse downloadResponse =
                              (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse())
                    using (Stream sourceStream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (Stream targetStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Luego leo los archivos del disco y los meto en un list

```
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\xxx.csv"))
            {
                List<string> listA = new List<string>();
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(';');

                    listA.Add(values[0]);

                }
            }
```

Mi pregunta:
Puedo leer los archivos sin tener que descargarlos a mi disco?

Comment: Can you translate it to spanish? :D

Comment: Perdón, pensaba que estaba en la versión en inglés...

Comment: no te vale borrar el archivo tras leerlo?

Comment: Es una opción, pero prefiero no tener que guardar en el disco nada

Comment: Yo no le veo el problema, como cuando coges un json de una rest api, no tienes que guardarlo, simplemente metes el json en una variable local y trabajas con ella, pues supongo que será algo así en tu caso, a ver si alguien te soluciona mejor las dudas

Comment: @Za7pi Podrías leer el archivo desde el FTP y guardarlo en memoria en vez de guardarlo

Answer (score 1):

Con este metodo no tienes que grabar el archivo localmente, lo envias directo del stream reader al List :

```
WebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(url);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    using( var reader = new StreamReader( responseStream, encode ))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');
            listA.Add(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con ese método lo que consigues es meter en un list los nombres de los archivos.Peeero: ¿Cómo consigues leer el interior del csv sin descargarlo?

Comment: No si "url" contiene la referencia a un archivo, con ese metodo se lee el archivo que se encuentra en "url" y se carga en un list<string> sin grabar el archivo en el disco, si en ese archivo hay una lista de archivos, o un dataset de cualquier otro tipo de informacion, eso no importa.